# Take a number of different occurrences in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I need some help with this task.

I have a pandas DataFrame that is something like this:

```
col1    col2
1         x
2         x
3         x
4         y
5         y
6         y
7         y
8         z
9         z
10        z
```

what I need is to take the first 2 occurrences of col1 for each different element in col2.
The output in this case should be [1,2,4,5,8,9]

I've no idea how to do it, I searched on StackOverflow and found only questions related to counting occurrences, I don't need to know how many x,y,z are in the column, I only need to take the first 2 for each one.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straight forward way to do this would be the following

```
[df.col1[df['col2'] == unique].tolist()[0:2] for unique in df.col2.unique()] 

[[1, 2], [4, 5], [8, 9]]
```

And to get the output you want, you can flatten the list.